# Tag score wrong calculation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, tag-score

Take a look at [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294606/atish-dipongkor).

He has bronze tag badge for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but not for [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and [linq](/questions/tagged/linq)(for those tags he has [scored more than 200](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294606/atish-dipongkor?tab=tags&sort=votes)).

The score calculation looks like wrong, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1294606%20%5Blinq%5D) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1294606%20%5B.net%5D).

[image]

But, it shows 216 for [.net](/questions/tagged/.net).

[image]

Comment: Some of the votes seem to be for questions?

Comment: The user only answered 8 and 11 questions in those two tags; you need at least 20 answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it's not a dupe, I've edited my question.

Comment: You changed the question. The tag scores are calculated *once a day*, 4 of those votes were cast **after** the tag scores were calculated.

Comment: Even if the tag scores were wrong, there are *still* fewer than 20 answers for those tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bronze badge requirement:

> You must have a total score of 100 in **at least 20 non-community wiki answers** to achieve this badge.

This user has 8 posts in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag and 11 posts in [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) tag. So requirement is not fulfilled.

---

**Regarding your edit**:

Tag scores are updated once a day. He earned 4 votes today that's why his score is 220 - 4 = **216** in his profile.

Comment: what about the score calculation?

Comment: @Azik - Requirement is not either score or number of answer. Both are required.

Comment: what is the tag score of .net tag for that user?

Comment: @Azik - Just hover your mouse on the number before the tag in his profile. (e.g. 232, 216 etc) :)

Comment: see my edited question.